# Ng-bootstrap timepicker.module has no exported member 'NgbTimeAdapter'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I updated @ng-bootstrap to the latest version 2.2.0 and I started receiving this error in my Angular project. The error seems to come from the 'timepicker' component but it was working perfectly fine in the previous version.

> Module '"/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.module"' has no exported member 'NgbTimeAdapter'.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: share your module code

Comment: Sorry I don't have the code now because I had to fix this quickly. What I did was reinstall the older version of ng-bootstrp. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somewhere cache is causing isues, Try completely removed my node_modules folder and reinstall  everything.

Related **[`Error`](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2444)**

Answer (score 0):

Else you can import the library directly like following :

```
import { NgbTimeAdapter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-date-adapter';
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop angular, and clear the cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then run angular again

```
ng s
```